# Как при помощи Python делать асинхронный post запрос раз в несколько секунд(до бесконечности)?

Tags: python, http, post, асинхронность

Как при помощи Python делать асинхронный post запрос раз в несколько секунд(до бесконечности)? На сервере, куда отправляется запрос - есть задержка в несколько секунд. После отправки запроса, эти несколько секунд программа висит, вместо того, чтобы отправить следующий запрос, не дожидаясь ответа от сервера. Пробовал так:

```
import json
from tornado import gen, httpclient, ioloop

ip = '127.0.0.1'
number_of_port = '8889'
http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()


@gen.coroutine
def post():
    data = {'device_id': '28', 'requst_id': '35', 'status': 'OK',
            'data': '{something information}'}
    request = httpclient.HTTPRequest('http://' + ip + ':' + number_of_port, 
                                    body=json.dumps(data), method="POST")
    print(data)
    response = yield http_client.fetch(request)
    print(response.body.decode('utf-8'))

while True:
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(post)
```

И так:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import random

ip = '127.0.0.1'
number_of_port = '8889'


async def fetch(session, url, data):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(0, loop=session.loop):
        async with session.post(url, json=data) as response:
            return await response.text(), response.headers

async def main(loop):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
            data = {'data': 'info'}
            print('Request:' + str(data))
            text, headers = await fetch(session, 'http://' + ip + ':' + 
                                        number_of_port, data)
            print(headers)
            print('Response:' + text + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Comment: И какие результаты попыток?)

Comment: @rusnasonov, как я писал - программа ожидает ответа от сервера(на сервере есть задержка в несколько секунд). Но запрос же асинхронный. Почему, во время ожидания программа не выполняет следующие инструкции до того, как придёт ответ? Или тут есть какой-то блокирующий код?